# While loop wouldn't stop looping

Tags: c, while-loop

I think I screwed up, my code is over looping(It won't stop). It would continue to loop even after 0 is entered. Please point out where did I do wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int day=1, exp=1, tallow;
    float allow,tday,daily, texpen;

    printf("\nDay %d allowance. [Type -1 to stop] --> ", day);
    scanf("%f", &allow);

    while(allow != -1){
        printf("-- Expenses %d [type 0 to stop]  ", exp);
        scanf("%f", &daily);exp++;
        while(daily == 0){
            printf("\nDay %d allowance : %.2f", day, allow);
            tday += daily;
            printf("\nDay %d expenses  : %.2f", day, tday);
            break;
        }
    }

        printf("\nTotal allowance for %d days : %.2f", day, tallow);
        printf("\nTotal expenses for %d days : %.2f\n", day, texpen);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

current output :

```
Day 1 allowance. [Type -1 to stop] --> 20

-- Expenses 1 [type 0 to stop]  5

-- Expenses 2 [type 0 to stop]  3

-- Expenses 3 [type 0 to stop] 0

Day 1 allowance : 20.00

Day 1 expenses  : 8.00 -- Expenses 4 [type 0 to stop]
```

how do I get rid of "Expenses 4"?/How do I stop it from looping after 0 is entered?

Comment: Define `allow` as `int` and not `float`.

Comment: Also you never set your allow to -1 so it will keep running. (**while allow!=-1** means you have to set it to -1 for the while to break)

Comment: First: Do you know why it doesn't do what you want it to do?

Comment: The inner loop `while(daily == 0){..}` ... never updates `daily`.  And never loops.  Why not just replace it with an "if"?  And replace "daily" with some integer value?  Read this: [Why doesn't my floating point comparision work?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/floating-point-arith.html)

Answer (score 1):

You may change your

```
    while(daily == 0){
```

to

```
    if(daily == 0){
```

so the break; will exit the loop of

```
    while(allow != -1){
```

then no more "Expenses 4" printed.

and also you need define your allow as int, with

```
scanf("%d", &allow);
```

it should be:

```
...
while(allow != -1){
    printf("-- Expenses %d [type 0 to stop]  ", exp);
    scanf("%f", &daily);exp++;
    tday += daily;
    if(daily == 0){
        printf("\nDay %d allowance : %.2f", day, allow);
        printf("\nDay %d expenses  : %.2f", day, tday);
        break;
    }
}
```